# Ruby: find all `<img>` tags that only have a `<br/>` immediately following it

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

Using Ruby, I am trying to find all `<img>` tags that have a `<br />` immediately afterward.

For example, this is what I am looking for:

```
<img src="http://img-example.jpg" alt="some description"><br />
```

But this would be an example of what I am *not* looking for:

```
<img src="http://img2-example.jpg" alt=""><span>Some extended text</span><img src="http://img3-example.jpg" alt="some more descriptions"><br />
```

In the second example, there is a `<br />` but it is not immediately preceded by the `<img>` tag and *only* the `<img>` tag.

I have tried Regex, and Nokogiri.
Albeit, my Ruby skills are pretty terrible.

Thoughts?
Is Nokogiri better?  If so, what is your recommendation?
Regex better?  If so, what is your recommendation for that?

I have used the following, but it returns true for both instances above:

```
img_with_break = string[/<img(.*?)alt=\"(.*?)\"><br \/>/]
```

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - use a parser, but anyway `<img[^>]*><br\s*\/?>`

Comment: @ctwheels  good answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
doc.search('img').select{|img| img.at('+ br')}
```

I would have thought just:

```
doc.search('img:has(+ br)')
```

but that doesn't work (bug in nokogiri)